# From where does target.logElementTree() retrieve information?

Tags: instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I am actually trying to list all the available controls in a particular screen in an app so I want to know from where exactly does target.logElementTree() retrieve the information ?? or how to retrieve the all the controls available on a particular screen from the view controller ??

I am using Xcode 6.3.2 , UIAutomation in Instruments.

Thank you for taking time to go through till the end .

Answer (score 0):

At present, this is provided by some private code within Instruments.

To access all the available elements, see [Apple's documentation on UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/), specifically [the section on determining the element hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009903-CH1-SW6).

Comment: I have gone through it previously and couldn't find so went on with my implementation ...